# What is meant by an object when you talk about databases?

Tags: database, oracle11g, definition

I was reading Oracle Database 11g The Complete Reference and came across the following line.

> You can create synonyms for the object
>   names, view objects in different databases (across database links), and restrict access to the
>   objects.

The chapter is supposed to familiarize the reader with terminology. I didn't understand what `object` meant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are the "things" that make up your database schema, like tables, views, stored procedures, functions and suchlike.

There's a more comprehensive list in [Oracle's documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm).

Comment: Oh! But then records wont count as objects?

Comment: @101 Correct. Records are not Objects in that sense. BUT Oracle has some Object Oriented Features, where Cells are considered Objects. But don't worry, if you try to use those you are screwed anyway.